# Where does bad behavior come from in Islam and what is the difference between a sin?

Tags: practical-islam

In Judaims and Christianity they have the term 'sin'. Originally the sin comes from the sin of Adam in the garden of eden. Does moslims don't believe that story in the garden? And how do moslims consider bad behaviour came in the world? Do they constitue that with the evolutiontheorie?

Comment: Yes, we believe in the [story of Adam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_in_Islam). But, we don't believe sins of ancestors have anything to do with *OUR* [sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_views_on_sin), because we've been given enough [intelligence](http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=67&verse=10) and Internet ( at least today ).

Comment: Ok, so Islam does use the word 'sin'. But what is the origin of it?

Comment: Perhaps, [Satan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satan) is the origin of it.

Comment: Your question in the title is not clear enough. What is the difference between a sin AND WHAT??

Answer (score 2):

All praise be to Allah:
Muslims do believe the story in the garden but i don't know if christians version of that story is same or somehow fabricated. SO the story muslims believe is this:

> And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "Indeed, I will make upon the earth a successive authority." They said, "Will You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds blood, while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?" Allah said, "Indeed, I know that which you do not know."
>  ... And [mention] when We said to the angels, "Prostrate before Adam"; so they prostrated, except for Iblees. He refused and was arrogant and became of the disbelievers.
> And We said, "O Adam, dwell, you and your wife, in Paradise and eat therefrom in [ease and] abundance from wherever you will. But do not approach this tree, lest you be among the wrongdoers."
> But Satan caused them to slip out of it and removed them from that [condition] in which they had been. And We said, "Go down, [all of you], as enemies to one another, and you will have upon the earth a place of settlement and provision for a time."
> Then Adam received from his Lord [some] words, and He accepted his repentance. Indeed, it is He who is the Accepting of repentance, the Merciful.
> We said, "Go down from it, all of you. And when guidance comes to you from Me, whoever follows My guidance - there will be no fear concerning them, nor will they grieve.
> And those who disbelieve and deny Our signs - those will be companions of the Fire; they will abide therein eternally."
> Quran 2/30-40

So this is the story of adam and eve told by quran in one place. Now comming to second part of your question.
Muslims don't believe that sin came because of adam and eve or their mistake. People do sin because of the same reason mentioned above **"Satan Caused them to slip"**. Satan is the biggest enemy of the man. He urges him to do the wrong.
Human being have the choice to do whatever they want to do. On one side they have teachings of God and his prophets. On other hand it is satan who is constantly trying that by any means he stay away from God and do wrong.

> And do not follow in the footsteps of satan. He truly is an outright enemy to you. (Surat Al-Baqara:168)

And

> I will lead them astray and fill them with false hopes. I will command them and they will cut off cattle’s ears. I will command them and they will change Allah’s creation.’ Anyone who takes satan as his protector in place of Allah has clearly lost everything. (Surat An-Nisa: 119)
>   And Satan had made pleasing to them their deeds and averted them from the path. [Quran 29:38]

This does not mean that shetan can lead man to anywhere he want, as quran says:

> Satan only has authority over those who take him as a friend and associate others with Allah.(Surat An-Nahl: 100)
>
> Satan has no authority over those who believe and put their trust in their Lord.(Surat An-Nahl: 99)
>
> Sincerely seeking refuge in Allah and the Qur'an would neutralize the evil impulses.(Surat Al-A'raf: 200-201) (Surah Fussilat: 36)
>
> He has no authority over those who have faith and put their trust in their Lord. (Surat An-Nahl: 99)

On the judgement day satan will say:

> And Satan will say when the matter has been concluded, "Indeed, Allah had promised you the promise of truth. And I promised you, but I betrayed you. But I had no authority over you except that I invited you, and you responded to me. So do not blame me; but blame yourselves. I cannot be called to your aid, nor can you be called to my aid. Indeed, I deny your association of me [with Allah] before. Indeed, for the wrongdoers is a painful punishment." [Quran 14:22]

And i will also recommend you to read a copy of english quran or in whatever language you like to read. Having a printed copy copy will be more beneficial. Reading quran you will better understand what islam really is.
Hope it helps. [Get a copy of quran from here in many languages](http://www.pdfquran.com/en/)